# PHP - Insert text after x words, but not inside tag

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have the following string:

`Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong>Aenean fermentum risus <strong><a href="https://google.com">id tortor.</a></strong> <strong>Suspendisse nisl.</strong> dictum at dui. Aenean id metus <strong><a href="https://google.com"> id velit</a>  ullamcorper pulvinar</strong>. Neque porro quisquam es qui dolorem ipsum.`

I need to insert text `read more` after 10th word, but only if it is not inside the html tag. To be more clear, I need to count the words (even those inside tags), find the 10th word, and if inside tag, continue to the end of the outer tag and insert the `read more` at that place.

Simple `explode by space` obviously doesn't work for this case. Anyone can help?

Comment: "if inside tag" - your snippet seems to be part of an HTML file; as such, **everything** is inside the root `<html>` tag.  So how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code, you can see the modified version of the given example text with the addition of the 'new text' after the 10th word.

```php
<?php
    function insertAfterTenWords($text, $insertion) {
        $words = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
        $wordCount = count($words);
        $openTags = [];
        $newText = '';
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < $wordCount; $i++) {
            $word = $words[$i];
            
            if (strpos($word, '<') !== false) {
                $openTags[] = substr($word, strpos($word, '<'));
                $newText .= $word . ' ';
            } else if (strpos($word, '>') !== false) {
                $lastTag = array_pop($openTags);
                $newText .= $word . ' ';
                
                while ($lastTag != substr($word, strpos($word, '<'))) {
                    $word = $words[++$i];
                    $newText .= $word . ' ';
                }
            } else {
                $newText .= $word . ' ';
            }
            
            if ($i == 9 && count($openTags) == 0) {
                $newText .= $insertion . ' ';
            }
        }
        
        while (count($openTags) > 0) {
            $newText .= array_pop($openTags);
        }
        
        return trim($newText);
    }
    
    $text = 'Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong>Aenean fermentum risus <strong><a href="https://google.com">id tortor.</a></strong> <strong>Suspendisse nisl.</strong> dictum at dui. Aenean id metus <strong><a href="https://google.com"> id velit</a>  ullamcorper pulvinar</strong>. Neque porro quisquam es qui dolorem ipsum.';
    $insertion = '<a href="#">new text</a>';
    
    echo insertAfterTenWords($text, $insertion);
?>
```